# Autoformatting LESS code with vim

Tags: css, vim, less, autoformatting

How to make vim format this LESS code properly? `=G` command gives horrific results.

Here is a sample:

```
// главный слайдер main slider
.herounit-row {
    position: relative;
}
.hero-box {
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    width:100%;
    .centered();
}
```

Here is how it looks after `gg=G`:

```
// главный слайдер main slider
.herounit-row {
position: relative;
}
.hero-box {
position:absolute;
top:0;
width:100%;
      .centered();
}
```

Answer (score 4):

If you want to use Vim's shipped filetypes, you can:

`:set ft=scss`

Afterwards `gg=G` should deliver the expected results.

EDIT: If it's working for all your use cases, you could also automate this via (I'm assuming the less file extension here):

`autoread BufNewFile,BufRead *.less set filetype=scss`

Comment: sadly, it made no difference to me.

Comment: What means no difference? Could you give the expected results in your question? Because the identation looks correct to me using the scss filetype.

Answer (score 1):

For me, this https://github.com/groenewege/vim-less worked nice.

But to be honest, I only see your `padding` line wrong, the rest seem ok.

This is your less code formated on my vim:

```
h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6 {
    font-family: @main-font;
}
.browse-button {
    .transition(0.4s all);
    line-height: 2.3em;
    padding: 0 13px 0 13px;
    background: @additional-color;
    font-size: 1em;
    border:none;
    color:#fff;
    white-space: nowrap;
    .border-radius(15px);
    &:hover {
        color:#dfdfdf;
        background:lighten(@additional-color, 10%);
    }
    &:active {
        box-shadow:inset 0px 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
    }
}
```

Comment: I also use vim-less, but it's still not working. I've clarified my question with a cleaner (and smaller) sample.